# Stop Mail from downloading attachments automatically

Tags: mac, mail.app

How to stop Mail.app (version 7.0) on my Mac OSX 10.9 from downloading attachments automatically.

I have setup my Gmail account, and I want to be given an option to download attachments instead of having them downloading automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to system preferences, select accounts. In accounts select Advanced and uncheck the option: "Automatically download all attachments"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of Apple Mail **version 10** (as of March 2017) the setting can be found in *Mail > Preferences > Accounts > Account Information*, as seen below:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You should actually go to "Mail" app, then "Preferences", then "Accounts", then "Advanced".
Not "System Preferences"